# can I travel with my Italian carta d'identita to Poland while only having Italian citizenship but not Italian nationality?

Tags: schengen, italy, identity-cards

I am considered an Italian citizen, but have US nationality and passport (but only an Italian "carta d'identita") Can I travel to Poland with my Italian document?

Comment: Can you explain the difference between being a cittizen and having the nationality? Ad far as I understand they are the same.

Comment: thanks Mark my card is actually still a paper one but it does say Italian under nationality and nothing about non valida per espatrio.
so it is good to go.

Comment: It is not possible to have Italian citizenship without having Italian nationality.  It is not possible to have US citizenship without having US nationality.  It is possible to have US nationality without having US citizenship.  If that describes you then your passport will say as much, but it's extremely unlikely (for example, if you were born in the US then you are a US citizen).  From the facts you've given, it seems that you have two citizenships (and two nationalities).

Comment: Also, you created two accounts ([bonnie lucas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/120560/bonnie-lucas) and [bonnie](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/120561/bonnie)).  You can merge them: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  Once you do that, you can add comments on your own questions.

Comment: Are you confusing Italian residence? Or are you stateless (so Italy will provide you a sort of documentation, but not nationality)?

Answer (score 4):

If the **carta d'identita** contains,  in the lower right hand corner, the words:

- **NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO**

and under nationality contains anything other than

- **ITA**

then you are **not** an Italian citizen, **nor is the card valid outside of Italy** and

- **cannot** be used for travelling outside of Italy

Italy is one of the few countries that issues an identity card to legal residents.

[image]

- this card has been issued to an Italian citizen

  - but is **not** valid for travel

---

[image]

- this card has been issued to an Italian citizen

  - and **is** valid for travel

---

| Paper version --- also possible with *NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO* stamp |
| --- |
| [image] |
| [image] |

---

**Sources**:

PRADO - Public Register of Authentic travel and identity Documents Online

- [ITA - Italy • REPUBBLICA ITALIANA](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-documents/ITA/index.html)

  - [List of all Documents](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-documents/ITA/all/docs-all.html)

    - [ITA-BO-04004, Identity card, Carta D'identita](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/ITA-BO-04004/index.html)
    - [ITA-BO-03001, Identity card, Carta D'identita](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/ITA-BO-03001/index.html)

Comment: I do not see a difference in the two pictures of the ID cards.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, hard to see. Lower right hand corner, above the red stripe and below the id number: is either empty (2nd image)  or contains the text: **NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO** (1st image).

Comment: if it is so not obvious, how is a border official in Poland able to tell? why make such an important distinction so obscure?

Comment: @dlatikay They would look at the PRADO database (or possibly a non public version thereof) for varification. As to the reason why Italy does it this way? Good question, but one where one will probably never get a real answer to.